# Подсказка при наведении курсора на объект

Tags: c, delphi

Как сделать отображение подсказки при наведении курсора на объект?

Comment: задержать мышку чуть дольше?

Comment: боже..... у меня нет слов. спасибо))) а как уменьшить это время?

Comment: @redisodix Вы смотрите подсказки в IDE или у себя в программе?

Comment: `как уменьшить это время` перевод  на английский слов "задержка подсказки" приводит вот сюда: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.HintPause

Answer (score 0):

- Для активации данной функции можно для формы установить свойство `ShowHint=true`, тогда всем дочерним элементам, которые поддерживают данное свойство (наследники `TControl`) будет установлено `ShowHint=true`. Если подсказка нужна для конкретного элемента - данное свойство нужно установить только ему.
- Также нужно заполнить поле `Hint` - это текст, который будет отображаться при наведении.

> О Parent* свойствах

Если мы изменим свойство `ShowHint` для определенного компонента, тогда автоматически свойство `ParentShowHint` станет `False` и обратно автоматически не вернется. Нужно это учитывать. Такое поведение присуще всем свойствам `Parent*`.

Comment: `которые поддерживают данное свойство` не совсем так. Будет установлено тем, у которых ParentShowHint = True.

Comment: @kami спасибо, дополнил ответ. Я имел в виду наследников `TControl`. `ParentShowHint` совсем выпал из головы.